Why general solution of system of differential equations or simultaneous equations are given in pair of relation?
So i am confused or interested in knowing why general solution for system of differential equation ( say system of 2 equation) is given by 2 ralations or a pair say u1(x,y,z)=c1 and u2(x,y,z)=c2 . Is it realted to size of system like 2 differential equations then 2 relations and if yes how? And yes i know how solutions of D.E are related to D.E itself. I am just interested can we give more then 2 relations for system of 2 and why always only 2 are used .
